# How to Force a [Para]Footmisc Footnote to Start on the Next Line

Tags: luatex, footnotes, line-breaking, footmisc, para

I am using the `footmisc` package.

Consider the code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[para]{footmisc}
%\usepackage{setspace}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

This is a sentence.\footnote{First footnote}
This is another sentence.\footnote{Second footnote}
This is another sentence.\footnote{Third footnote}
This is another sentence.\footnote{Fourth footnote}
This is another sentence.\footnote{Fifth footnote}
This is another sentence.\footnote{Sixth footnote}
This is another sentence.\footnote{Seventh footnote.}
\end{document}
```

which produces the footnote display:

[image]

QUESTION: I would like to have, in this case, the fifth footnote begin on the second line, instead breaking onto the second line part of the way through. How may this be accomplished? I compile the code with `lualatex`.

Thank you.

Comment: You could put its contents into an `\mbox`? If the content of the footnote is small and you need to do it on an ad hoc basis, that's a simple solution.

Comment: @AlanMunn Thank you for this helpful suggestion for when the footnote is short in length.

Comment: @AlanMunn not sure this is a good idea: it means that this particular footnote is set with spaces at nominal width, while all other spaces in the footnotes stretch and shrink as necessary. Better use `Fifth~footnote`, i.e., nonbreakable but stretchable spaces.

Comment: @FrankMittelbach I agree that it's not ideal, but adding a non-breaking space simply causes the following word to hyphenate at least in this example, which doesn't actually solve the problem.  But I agree that trying `~` first would be the preferred strategy.

Comment: @AlanMunn so you say, but you are mistaken - have you tried it? footmisc doesn't hyphenate the footnotes. The reason is that it formats them into an \hbox first and then unboxes those and TeX optimizes that by not running the hyphenation algorithm in that case.  So only hyphenation if you put some explicitly in with \-.

Comment: @FrankMittelbach Did you try it? :) With `lualatex` (which is being used here) the footnote is hyphenated, though not with `pdflatex`.

Comment: @AlanMunn you are right LuaTeX doesn't make this "optimization" (which is, these days normally a pain rather than a gain). I haven't noticed  the tag "luatex" at the bottom, the example didn't shouted luatex to me - my fault

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is not really a nice interface for this, but as suggested by @AlanMunn one way can be to force a number of words on the the same line. However one should *never* do this by putting several words into an `\mbox` if they then appear in the middle of a paragraph that is justified as usual. If you do this you get something like

```
\hbox to \linewidth{A line \mbox{of text that} looks ugly}
```

producing something like

[image]

Instead, use `~` (non-breaking spaces) between words, e.g., `Fifth~footnote` in the example.

In situations where words, can get hyphenated, you have to do even more and write `Fifth~\mbox{footnote}~\mbox{...}` which is ugly input but gives you nice output.

However, the footmisc code uses horizontal boxes to store the footnotes and TeX optimizes that by not adding hyphenation points to text that goes into `\hbox`es and doesn't add them either when such boxes are later unboxed.
Thus in the above example all that is needed are `~` instead of normal spaces.

Having said that ... this is only true for pdfTeX or XeTeX. LuaTeX does away with this optimization so there you do need to input in the more painful manner.

Comment: Thank you for providing this information.